# Cant insert into database?

Tags: php

```
<?php
// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("corporate_personnel_order_for_2016") or die(mysql_error());

@$mode = $_POST['mode'];
@$OBS_NUMBER = $_POST['OBS_NUMBER'];
@$NAME = $_POST['NAME'];
@$PURPOSE = $_POST['PURPOSE'];
@$DATE_OF_OB = $_POST['DATE_OF_OB'];
@$DESTINATION = $_POST['DESTINATION'];
@$SELF = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];


if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if(getimagesize($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']) == FALSE)
    {
        echo "Please select an image.";
    }
    else
    {
        $image= addslashes($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
        //$name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image= file_get_contents($image);
        $image= base64_encode($image);
        saveimage($OBS_NUMBER, $NAME, $PURPOSE, $DATE_OF_OB,$DESTINATION,$image);
    }

    function saveimage($OBS_NUMBER, $NAME, $PURPOSE, $DATE_OF_OB,$DESTINATION,$image)
    {
        $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("corporate_personnel_order_for_2016",$con);
        mysql_query ("INSERT INTO obs (OBS_NUMBER, NAME, PURPOSE,DATE_OF_OB,DESTINATION,IMAGESOBS) VALUES ('$OBS_NUMBER', '$NAME', '$PURPOSE','$DATE_OF_OB','$DESTINATION', '$image' )");
    }
}

print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    print 'alert("Add Successful")';
print '</script>';
?>
```

Comment: are u getting errors? plz use mysqli or PDO..mysql_* is deprecated and closed in php 7

Comment: move toward `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. `mysql_*` is deprecated now. Also remove `@` to get actual errors. don't skip errors

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: `echo "INSERT INTO obs (OBS_NUMBER, NAME, PURPOSE,DATE_OF_OB,DESTINATION,IMAGESOBS) VALUES ('$OBS_NUMBER', '$NAME', '$PURPOSE','$DATE_OF_OB','$DESTINATION', '$image' )"`  u will get the idea, about your query

Comment: Please show us your `<form></form>` code too.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
if(!$con)
{
    echo "Could not connect to the server";
}
if(! mysqli_select_db($con,'database_name'))
{
    echo "Cannot select the database";
}
```

Comment: make use of var_dump() to check whether the values are retrieving or not

Comment: *Why User Will Try This ?* An Explanation Makes Answer More Better.

Comment: He told the values are not inserting to the database and no errors too... So have to make sure whether the the values are passed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","654321","testV2") or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($con));

// Write query

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }

// Close the connection
mysqli_close($con);
  ?>
```

Comment: my insert query cant insert the values  into database

Comment: @jonasgmarao first check if database connection is done or not?

Comment: their is no error but it cant insert to my database

Comment: change this $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("corporate_personnel_order_for_2016",$con); to mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","password","database")

Answer (score 0):

try executing you're insert query manually in mysql see if you get errors

also try having only one mysql_connect and mysql_select_db